# call Google matrix distance api through store procedure sql server

Tags: stored-procedures, google-api

I Want To Call Distance Matrix Api Of Google Through Stored Procedure....So that I Will Pass Two Parameters As Origin And Destination and Get Distence And Hours As Result From SP....Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I Have Done It...I Am Posting It If Later Any Body Need This....I Make An SP Here...Pass Pin Codes as Parameters to  it and get Distance As Result..

USE [CalculateDistance]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CalculateDistence]    Script Date: 12/1/2014 12:49:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Rajay Sachdeva>
-- Create date: <Create 25/11/2014,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateDistence] --'','','','37064','','','','78701',''
(
@ToAddress varchar(100) =null,
@ToCity varchar(100)=null,
@ToState varchar(100)=null,
@ToPostCode varchar(100)=null,
@FromAddress varchar(100)=null,
@FromCity varchar(100)=null,
@FromState varchar(100)=null,
@FromPostCode varchar(100)=null,
@DistanceInKilometers varchar(100) output
)
AS

     Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Declare @serviceUrl as varchar(500)
  set @serviceUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=' +@ToAddress+@ToCity+@ToState+@ToPostCode+
   '&destinations=' +@FromAddress+@FromCity+@FromState+ @FromPostCode +'&mode=driving&language=en-EN&units=metric;'
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                @serviceUrl, --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Declare @Response as XML

--Select @ResponseText as XMLList

SET @Response = CAST(@ResponseText AS XML);

  Declare @Status as varchar(20)
   Declare @Distance as varchar(20)


  set @Status= @Response.value('(DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/status)[1]', 'varchar(20)') 
  print @Status
  if(@Status='ZERO_RESULTS')

   Begin

                     set @Distance=@Status
   End
   else

   Begin
   set @Distance=@Response.value('(DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/text)[1]', 'varchar(20)') 
   End
  --Select @Response.value('(DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/text)[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Distance 
  select @Distance as Distance
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but this also works:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateGoogleDistance]
    (
    @Latitude1   nvarchar(1000),
    @Longitude1  nvarchar(1000),
    @Latitude2   nvarchar(1000),
    @Longitude2  nvarchar(1000)
    )
returns nvarchar(1000)
as

begin


DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + @Latitude1 + ' ' + @Longitude1 + ')', 4326);
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + @Latitude2 + ' ' + @Longitude2 + ')', 4326);


DECLARE @dist float
DECLARE @distType varchar(10)

if FLOOR(CONVERT(float, @g.STDistance(@h)))  < 100
BEGIN
SET @dist = FLOOR(CONVERT(float, @g.STDistance(@h)))
SET @distType = 'cm'
END

ELSE if FLOOR(CONVERT(float, @g.STDistance(@h)))  < 1000
BEGIN
SET @dist = FLOOR(CONVERT(float, @g.STDistance(@h)))
SET @distType = 'm'
END
ELSE    
BEGIN
SET @dist = FLOOR(CONVERT(float, @g.STDistance(@h))/1000)
SET @distType = 'km'
END

return CAST(@dist as nvarchar(1000)) + ' ' + @distType


end
```

Comment: Using direct distance